# With ec2 python API boto, how to get spot instance_id from SpotInstanceRequest?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

When using *boto*, Amazon aws python API.

```
ec2_connection.request_spot_instances(...)
# This will return an ResultSet of SpotInstanceRequest
```

How can I get instance_ids from the `SpotInstanceRequest`?

**UPDATE:** I did it this way, after a lot playing and googleing, hope this help:

```
ec2_connection.get_all_spot_instance_requests(request_ids=[my_spot_request_id, ])
```

This will return the *updated* `SpotInstanceRequest`, when the *instance* is ready, we can get *instance_id* from it.

Answer (score 6):

I did something similar: check periodically to see if the spot instance request id returned by 
`ec2_connection.request_spot_instances(...)`
 is matched to an instance in the results of 
`conn.get_all_spot_instance_requests(...)`
 :

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region_name=region_name, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
req = conn.request_spot_instances(price=MAX_SPOT_BID,instance_type=instance_type,image_id=AMI_ID,availability_zone_group=region_name,key_name=KEY_PAIR_PEM[:-4],security_groups=security_groups)
job_instance_id = None
while job_instance_id == None:
    print "checking job instance id for this spot request"
    job_sir_id = req[0].id # spot instance request = sir, job_ is the relevant aws item for this job
    reqs = conn.get_all_spot_instance_requests()
    for sir in reqs:
        if sir.id == job_sir_id:
            job_instance_id = sir.instance_id
            print "job instance id: " + str(job_instance_id)
            break
    time.sleep(SPINUP_WAIT_TIME)
```

Comment: Instead of doing ```while job_instance_id == None:``` you can do in a more pythonic way - ```while not job_instance_id:```

Answer (score 0):

```
spot_instance_requests = aws.ec2_get_connection().request_spot_instances(...)
MAX_MINUTES = 180
spot_instance_request_ids = [sir.id for sir in spot_instance_requests]
for _ in range(MAX_MINUTES):
    log.info('waiting for spot instances to start', request_ids=spot_instance_request_ids, seconds=60)
    time.sleep(60)
    spot_instance_requests = aws.ec2_get_connection().get_all_spot_instance_requests(
        request_ids=spot_instance_request_ids)
    if any(sir.instance_id for sir in spot_instance_requests):
        log.info('spot instance started. waiting...', seconds=60*5)
        time.sleep(60*5)
        break
else:
    raise Exception("Spot instances didn't start in {0} minutes!".format(MAX_MINUTES))
```